# Как сделать правильно раздачу ключей

Tags: python, dict

Нужен телеграм бот, где из словаря будет доставаться ключ из отправляться человеку и делать это циклично, чтобы каждому был разный ключ.

Вот пример

```
import telebot
import keys

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_keys(m):
    list_keys = keys.unique_text
    try:
        for elem in list_keys.keys():
            user_key = list_keys[elem]
            print(user_key)
    except KeyError:
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, text=constants.sorry,
                         parse_mode="Markdown", disable_web_page_preview=True)
```

Сейчас бот выдает всем один и тот же ключ, который последний в словаре.
Как выглядит словарь:

```
unique_text = {1: 'K8LG6-XGBTM-65*TD',
               2: 'KJBYA-K3J2K-FL*QI',
               3: 'X9YM2-EXBEF-0K*ND',
               4: '2T40H-RLBWW-7A*YX',
               5: 'K8LG6-XGBTM-65*TD',
               6: 'X9YM2-EXBEF-0K*ND',
               7: '2T40H-RLBWW-7A*YX',
               8: 'K8LG6-XGBTM-65*TD',
               9: 'KJBYA-K3J2K-FL*QI',
               10: 'X9YM2-EXBEF-0K*ND',
               11: '2T40H-RLBWW-7A*YX',
               12: 'K8LG6-XGBTM-65*TD',
               13: 'KJBYA-K3J2K-FL*QI',
               14: 'X9YM2-EXBEF-0K*ND',
               15: '2T40H-RLBWW-7A*YX'}
```

Как правильно это организовать?

Comment: а выданные ключи могут повторяться?

Comment: Не понятно, что конкретно Вы хотите и что делает код. Ведь он возвращает `None` (или я что-то не понимаю?) Может, Вам следует создать список и использовать его метод `pop`? Этот метод возвращает и удаляет последний элемент списка.